# db not defined error in `mongoDB` using `Meteor Js`

Tags: meteor

Below is my sample code ,if run this code ***db not defined error*** is came how to to solve this error.But my in tension is user details are store in `mongoDb` after submit the form .And send the `mongodb` command prompt operations .Plz Help me any body.....

```
user = new Meteor.Collection('test');

//Metro Client

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.hello.events({
    'submit #loginform' : function (e , t) 
{
        e.preventDefault();
      var username = t.find('#username').value;
          var password = t.find('#password').value;
      var email=t.find('#email').value;

   //Insert values Into mongodb
          user.insert
        ({
          username:username,
          password: password,
      email:email,

        });
    j = { name : "username" }
        db.test.insert( j );
    console.log("username="+username);
        console.log("password="+password);
    console.log("email="+email);
    }
  });
 // Send email is client
 Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            'xxxx@.com',
            'yyyy@gmail.com',
            'Hello from Meteor!');

}

//Metro Server

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

  });

 // Send email is Server

      Meteor.methods({
      sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
        //console.log("email="+to);
         process.env.MAIL_URL =      'smtp://AAAA@gmail.com:****@smtp.gmail.com:587'; 

        check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);
        this.unblock();
        Email.send({
          to: to,
          from: from,
          subject: subject,
          text: text
        });
      }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mongo shell, you would insert into a collection called 'test' like so:

```
db.test.insert(...);
```

In meteor, you would insert into a collection defined as follows:

```
Test = new Meteor.Collection('test');
```

with a command like:

```
Test.insert(...);
```

Your code is assuming that the object `db` is defined, like it would be in a mongodb shell. It isn't. You would need to change the line to:

```
user.insert(j);
```

When using meteor, you can't issue mongo shell commands from your code - you can only perform operations on collection objects like `Test`. Those changes will then be reflected in your database. While `meteor` is running, you can see this by opening a new terminal in your project's root directory and typing:

```
$ meteor mongo
```

That will open a mongo shell where you can access the data directly like:

```
db.test.findOne();
```

---

Please note that if you are using meteor to store users and passwords, you should use the built-in `accounts-password` package.